# Existence of solution based on convergence of finite-difference scheme

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

Consider the following boundary value problem
$$
\begin{cases}
y''(x)=p(x)y'(x)+q(x)y(x)+r(x)\\
y(0)=\alpha,\quad y(1)=\beta.
\end{cases}
$$
for continuous $p(x)$, $q(x)$, $r(x)$ and positive $q(x)>0$.

According to Section 8.1 of "A friendly introduction to numerical analysis" by Brian Bradie solution exists based on convergence of finite-difference scheme.

Is there any other, more classical way to show solvability of this problem?

Edit: I figured it out, the equation can be rewritten as $(v(x)y'(x))'=q(x)v(x)y(x)+r(x)v(x)$ with $v'(x)=-p(x)v(x)$. In the result, the corresponding bilinear form would be coercive.

Comment: Lax-Milgram theorem is the standard (?) way to prove existence of weak solutions.

Comment: I am struggling to show that corresponding bilinear functional is coercive